# Android ImageView glitch when scrolling a listview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a listview where each row looks like the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/horizontal_row_deal">


  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="#EFECE5"
              android:layout_weight="1">
      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail1"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"/>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myImageViewText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/thumbnail1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/thumbnail1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/thumbnail1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#80000000"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="#EFECE5"
              android:layout_weight="1">
      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail2"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"/>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myImageViewText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/thumbnail2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/thumbnail2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/thumbnail2"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#80000000"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="#EFECE5"
              android:layout_weight="1">
      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail3"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"/>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myImageViewText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/thumbnail3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/thumbnail3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/thumbnail3"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#80000000"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Visually this is supposed to look like 3 images in a row with a textview on top of the image  covering about 35 percent of it. The text view is somewhat transparent with a black background so that the image can still be seen on the back.

This works as intended when I am not scrolling the list. When I do scroll though, a part of the imageview goes on top of the textview as if it is glitching. Does anybody know what's going on and why this is happening?

Comment: maybe the little scrollbar on the right reduces the available size inside the listview by a small amount which messes with your layouts?

Comment: I increased padding so that the scrollbar does not overlap with the listview and it still occurs. I don't think its the scrollbar. :(

Comment: I think it's something to do with transparency and optimization. Try to call invalidate() on every scroll either on your textviews or your imageviews. (or the listview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure but try to add `android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"` to your list view as this removes any kind of flickring on list scrolling...may be this is the reason in this case also.....